LFS 7.8 Compiling Error GCC-5.2.0 - Pass 1
I apologise in advance for the poor formatting of this post this is new to me
I am currently trying to build LFS 7.8 using gentoo as the host system, unfortunately I can't figure out how to fix this compiling error on GCC pass 1
configure: loading cache ./config.cache
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu checking host system type... none-unknown-linux-gnu
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /bin/install -c checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for none-unknown-linux-gnu-strip... no
checking for strip... strip
configure: WARNING: using cross tools not prefixed with host triplet checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... gawk
[checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles... no configure: WARNING: the "none" host is obsolete, use --disable-assembly
checking ABI=standard
checking compiler gcc -g -02 ... no, long long reliability test 1
checking for none-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables...
checking whether we are cross compiling... yes
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C99... none needed
checking for gcc option to accept ISO Standard C... (cached) none needed
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking build system compiler gcc... no
configure: error: Specified CC_FOR_BUILD doesn't seem to work
make[1]: *** [Makefile: 4498: configure-gmp] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/mnt/lfs/sources/gcc-build' make: *** [Makefile: 859: all] Error 2

The only theory i have is that it would come from the fact that the packages specified in the Host Requirements are newer versions on gentoo
here is the output of the version check script in Host Requirements :
bash, version 5.2.37(1)-release
/bin/sh -> /usr/bin/bash
Binutils: (Gentoo 2.42 p6) 2.42.0 bison (GNU Bison) 3.8.2
/usr/bin/yacc -> /usr/bin/yacc.bison bzip2, Version 1.0.8, 13-Jul-2019. Coreutils: 9.5
diff (GNU diffutils) 3.10
find (GNU findutils) 4.10.0
GNU Awk 5.3.1, API 4.0
/usr/bin/awk -> /usr/bin/gawk
gcc (Gentoo 14.2.1_p20241116 p3) 14.2.1 20241116
g++ (Gentoo 14.2.1_p20241116 p3) 14.2.1 20241116 (Gentoo 2.40-r5 (patchset 5)) 2.40
grep (GNU grep) 3.11
gzip 1.13
Linux version 6.6.62-gentoo-dist (portage@localhost) (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-gcc (Gentoo 14.2.1_p20241116 p3) 14.2.1 20241116, GNU ld (Gentoo 2.42 p6) 2.42.0) #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Sun Nov 24 22:37:56 UTC 2024
m4 (GNU M4) 1.4.19
GNU Make 4.4.1
GNU patch 2.7.6
Perl version='5.40.0';
sed (GNU sed) 4.9
Star (GNU tar) 1.35
texi2any (GNU texinfo) 7.1.1
xz (XZ Utils) 5.6.3
g++ compilation OK

Apart from that I am lost
(Yes i am aware this is an old version of LFS and if i could do the latest one i would)
Thank you!
